# Получить пиксель картинки при клике сохраняя в массив / JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, элементы-управления

Всем привет. Я совсем новичок и вообще не понимаю как сделать подобное, если не сложно можете объяснить подробно что к чему.

**Задача**: Есть две картинки, при клике на которые, нужно считать их цвета в массив и выводить на экран.

```
        <div class="stone" id="color_bk">
            <img src="img/stone.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" id="but_color">
        </div>
        <div class="sholk" id="color__bk">
            <img src="img/sholk.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" id="but__color" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен Вашей помощи. Спасибо

Comment: как должен быть представлен цвет в массиве?

Comment: нужно взять канву, нарисовать эти картинки на ней, потом можно будет получить данные о цветах, через метод `ctx.getImageData`

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/185/how-to-get-the-pixel-color-from-a-canvas-on-click-or-mouse-event-with-javascript

Comment: @doox911 большое спасибо))
ещё вопрос, может быть он будет смешным
Если у меня две картинки, мне для каждой нужно будет прописывать разные функции?

Comment: Ну можно класс задать